# Error parsing yaml with exclamation marks

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, mkdocs

Trying to use `pyyaml` to parse `mkdocs.yml` file. It contains a snippet like this:

```yaml
foo:
    emoji_index: !!python/name:materialx.emoji.twemoji
```

When I run:

```py
with open("test.yml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        print(yaml.safe_load(stream))
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

This throws the following error:

```
could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/name:materialx.emoji.twemoji'
  in "test.yml", line 2, column 18
```

Answer (score 1):

`safe_load` restricts the loader to load only types it knows. This is because loading arbitrary types can lead to arbitrary code execution, which is a security risk.

To properly load the file, you have the following options:

- Use `load` instead of `safe_load` and import the library that contains `materialx.emoji.twemoji` (I am unsure where this is defined, I didn't find a definite answer online)
- Instead of loading the YAML file to native types, load it into a node graph using `yaml.compose`. This will return the root node of the YAML document. This will not put the nodes directly into `dict`s, `list`s etc.
- Register an own constructor:

```py
def my_constructor(loader, node):
  # since the content of the node is empty, you should return a value that
  # can be used to identify the node, e.g.
  return "materialx.emoji.twemoji"

yaml.add_constructor('tag:yaml.org,2002:python/name:materialx.emoji.twemoji',
    my_constructor, yaml.SafeLoader)
```

Which approach is the best depends on what you want to do with the data.